How to recreate Android metadata on video?
I need to generate a video using ffmpeg so that its metadata cannot be distinguished from a video shot with an Android smartphone camera (metadata headers must match and values must be generated correctly). Is it possible to do this? Perhaps there are already libraries on JS\ npm modules that can do this?
Basically I need to simulate the same thing that the Android camera software does, only in JS on my computer.
I tried to transfer metadata from video shot on a real smartphone to the created video using exiftool. But as a result such values as ‘Android Video Temporal Layers Count’ are not transferred. Moreover, such values as ‘Audio Bits Per Sample’ may differ from video to video and therefore copying them is not suitable.

It's challenging to perfectly replicate Android smartphone camera metadata for a video generated with ffmpeg.
